# Metro UI Horizontal Accordin

Tags: metro-ui-css

I found how to make a [vertical Accordion in Metro UI](http://metroui.org.ua/accordion.html).

But I would like to make a horizontal one.

Is it possible? If so, how do I proceed please?

Comment: I believe this can be done using css manipulation, however a lot of modifications may be required to achieve a good result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly then in the link you provided by adding the following css to the first div.cell:

```
.cell{width: 100%;}/*the div container containing the frame classes*/
.frame{float: left;}
.frame .heading, .frame .content{width: 200px;};/*you can choose the width you prefer but I guess they have to be the same width*/
```

you will get something like this:
[image]

You could also enable overflow in the '.frame .content' class if need be. Hope it helps.